# troubleshooting a value error in Python Django

Tags: python, django-views, django-1.8

```
error:
ValueError at /productcatalog/

Cannot assign "1L": "CartItem.user" must be a "User" instance.
```

I am trying to troubleshoot an error I receive when trying to view certain pages (locally)

I am not sure what I am missing and my trace seems to point to one line in particular in one of my views:

```
def index(request):
product = Product.objects.all()[:5]
category = Category.objects.all()
basket, created = CartItem.objects.get_or_create(status=0, user=request.user.id)
return render_to_response('index.html', {'category': category,
                          "product": product, 'basket': basket},
                          RequestContext(request))
```

specifically line

```
basket, created = CartItem.objects.get_or_create(status=0, user=request.user.id)
```

Here are my Views.py imports:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from productcatalog.models import Product, Category, Manufacturer
from django.conf import settings
from basket.models import CartItem
```

Can someone see where I have gone wrong?

Comment: The error message is quite clear. Django wants an instance of your User class and not the number 1. 1 is not an instance of User, it's a number. You need to pass in an instance of a User.

Answer (score 0):

Use `user=request.user` instead of `user=request.user.id`